# grep pattern for getting words having alternate consonants and vowels

Tags: unix

I have a text file `file1.txt` containing the following words

- abcdefghis
- abacadafag
- cdefghijka
- bedefegehj
- cidifigihi

**Question**: How will I get the words with alternating consonants and vowels using `grep` pattern?
My expected output is like this:

```
abacadafag
cidifigihi
```

So far I have this code but it only displays words with alternating consonant and vowel on the first 2 characters.

```
cat file1.txt | grep -i '^[^aeiou][aeiou]'
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your desired regex is the following:

```
^[aeiou]?([^aeiou][aeiou])+[^aeiou]?$
```

**^[aeiou]?** Matches any vowel 0 or 1 times (**?**) at the beginning of the string (**^**)

**([^aeiou][aeiou])+** Matches any consonant followed by a vowel 1 or more times (**+**)

**[^aeiou]?$** Matches any consonant 0 or 1 times (**?**) right before the end of the string (**$**)

Comment: Nice! this solution is superior to the one that I provided!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This solution worked great. Accepted this. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the first ^, grep -i '[^aeiou][aeiou]'